# Symfony execute an entity method using eval

Tags: php, eval

I am trying to run an Entity method using a string based method. But this doesn't seem to work and gives the following error:

> Notice: Undefined property: AppBundle\Entity\User::$setName

In controller

```
$user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("AppBundle:User")->find(1);
$value = "Peter";
$method = "setName(".$value.")";

eval($user->$method);

/**Tried this also but same error **/
$user->{$method}
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Using your second method it should be like this: `$user->{$method}($value)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you have to change your `$method` variable to a simple function/method name, then you can evaluate it like last row

```
$user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("AppBundle:User")->find(1);
$value = "Peter";
// Just the method name
$method = "setName";
// This is a valid evaluation passing a variable
$user->{$method}($value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Jack Skeletron's answer is closer to what you were trying to do, but you can also do it with the `call_user_func_array` function:

```
$user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("AppBundle:User")->find(1);

$method = 'setName';
$value = 'Peter';

call_user_func_array(array($user, $method), array($value));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php